# (Solved) Undefined function in webform_civicrm

Tags: drupal, webform-civicrm

Drupal 7, Civi 7.x-5.11.0

I've installed the latest webform module and the most recent webform_civicrm from Github.

I'm getting the following error when submitting or trying to access webform submissions:

Error: Call to undefined function wf_crm_apivalues() in webform_civicrm_webform_submission_load() (line 316 of /sites/all/modules/webform_civicrm/webform_civicrm.module).

Any ideas where I can look or advice to fix?

Thanks, Davy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for letting us know about the problem. I've just [pushed a fix](https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/commit/4d3ef15361d4ab0a634c18b96eb55af3d319eb15) into the 7.x-4.x branch to ensure the function gets loaded. You can update your local copy of the module (`cd /path/to/modules/webform_civicrm && git pull`) and try again.

Comment: Hi Coleman - thank you very much for helping out so quickly.

Answer (score 1):

If you've installed from github you're installing a beta or maybe even alpha version. In fact I can see that line 316 listed in the error message was only added 6 days ago! There are links at the bottom of the drupal project page to stable versions - use those instead.
https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm

Comment: Thanks Demerit for getting to this first; I’ll check with Coleman on line 316 

Comment: Thanks Demerit - I used the Github version because it has fixes for other functionality I needed eg https://github.com/colemanw/webform_civicrm/pull/182

I hope I'm not creating more challenges for myself :-/